# How to perform action while any EditText is selected?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am writting an application on android and I have a login activity. So when someone selects any of the `EditTexts`, layout goes up on given height, else layout goes to it original position; all the animation is created like this

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.editText1 || v.getId() == R.id.editText2 || v.getId() == R.id.editText3) {
        final ObjectAnimator moveDownAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageLayout, "translationY", 0.F, -370);
        final ObjectAnimator moveUpAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageLayout, "translationY", 370, 0.F);

        if (hasFocus) {
            moveDownAnim.start();
        } else {
            moveUpAnim.start();
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that when someone selects e.g. `editText1`it all goes up, but when user goes straight form `editText1` to `editText2`, firstly layout goes down and then again up. Is there any way to avoid it and keep layout up till user clicks on something that isn't `EditText`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. That's a bit around solution, but still, it works :)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    final ObjectAnimator moveDownAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(gridLayout, "translationY", 0.F, -370);
    final ObjectAnimator moveUpAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(gridLayout, "translationY", 370, 0.F);

     if(v.getId() == R.id.editText1 || v.getId() == R.id.editText2 || v.getId() == R.id.editText3) {
    {
        if(up == false) {
            moveDownAnim.start();
        }
    }
    else if (!(v.getId() == R.id.editText1 || v.getId() == R.id.editText2 || v.getId() == R.id.editText3)){}
    else{
        moveUpAnim.start();
        up = false;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.editText1 || v.getId() == R.id.editText2 || v.getId() == R.id.editText3){
        if(hasFocus){
            up = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the class name using `v.getClass().getSimpleName()`. If the `View` is an `EditText`, it will return a string whose value is `EditText`. 
You can change your code like this:

```
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

if(v.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("EditText")) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.editText1 || v.getId() == R.id.editText2 || v.getId() == R.id.editText3) {
        final ObjectAnimator moveDownAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageLayout, "translationY", 0.F, -370);
        final ObjectAnimator moveUpAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageLayout, "translationY", 370, 0.F);

        if (hasFocus) {
            moveDownAnim.start();
        } else {
            moveUpAnim.start();
        }
    }
}
else
{
/// NOT EditText, do whatever you want here
}
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the animation is still jumping when I jump between `EditText` :(

Comment: Why don't you try and  set a separate `OnFocusChangeListener` only for the 3 EditTexts and a general one for all the other views.

Comment: Seems like there is no effect with that also

Comment: I solved a problem by puting the animation to `onTouch`. The only problem that remains is that when I try to do get layout coordinates with `layout.getTop()` and etc it returns incorrect result. Shoul I use something else?